# Does "System" font mean the San Francisco font?

Tags: ios, xcode

The question is "where is the San Francisco" font? Is the "System" font the same thing?
Thanks!

[image: Xcode_view_of_fonts]

Created a new Xcode project and added a label. Then I tried to adjust the font without making it custom.

Comment: SF is the system font